# Splitting a list of integers into list of sublist in prolog

Tags: prolog

I am just learning Prolog and I am required to provide a list consisting of positive and negative integers to a function and it should return a list of sublist such that each sublist consists of either consecutive positive numbers only or consecutive negative numbers only. What I mean is based on the sign of the number present in the list, the function should break the list.

Following is the input and required output:

```
f([9,-10,-30,0,22,0,-40], L).
L = [[9], [-10, -30], [0, 22, 0], [-40]]
```

What I have achieved till now is:

```
f([],[]).
f([H|[]],L).
f([H,E|T],[[H,E|Tail1]|Tail]):-
    H >=0,
    E>=0,
    f(T,[[Tail1]|Tail]).

f([H,E|T],[[H]|Tail]) :-
    H>=0,
    E<0,
    f([E|T],Tail).

f([H,E|T],[[H,E|Tail1]|Tail]) :-
    H<0,
    E<0,
    f(T,[[Tail1]|Tail]).

f([H,E|T],[[H]|Tail]) :-
    H<0,
    E>=0,
    f([E|T],Tail).
```

I am getting weird trace while running the above function. Any help would be great. Thanks :)

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "weird"? Does your predicate (not function) do what you wish? If not, what is it actually doing? Note you'll need to rethink `f([H|[]], L).`. Both `H` and `L` are singleton here, so could literally be *anything* and this clause will succeed. So `f([a], [1,2,3]).` succeeds. Just a notation comment: `[H|[]]` can simply be written as `[H]`.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `fold/4` to split the list:

```
split(Input, LOutput):-
  foldl(addorsplit, Input, state(_Sgn, LOutput), state(_, [[]])).

sgn(Num, Sgn):-
  Sgn is sign(sign(Num)*2+1).

addorsplit(Item, state(Sgn, LOutput), state(NSgn, [Current|Tail])):-
  sgn(Item, NSgn),
  (Sgn = NSgn -> LOutput=[[Item|Current]|Tail] ; LOutput=[[],[Item|Current]|Tail]).
```

`sgn/2` is a helper procedure to let 0 be on the positives' side.

Sample query:

```
?- split([1,2,-3,-4,5,0,7],L).
L = [[1, 2], [-3, -4], [5, 0, 7]]
```

Using clp(FD) will allow to do more general queries:

```
split2(Input, LOutput):-
  foldl(addorsplit2, Input, state(_Sgn, LOutput), state(_, [[]])).

sgn2(Num, 1):-
  Num #>= 0.
sgn2(Num, -1):-
  Num #< 0.

addorsplit2(Item, state(Sgn, LOutput), state(NSgn, [Current|Tail])):-
  sgn2(Item, NSgn),
  (Sgn #= NSgn -> LOutput=[[Item|Current]|Tail] ; LOutput=[[],[Item|Current]|Tail]).
```

And now you can query for e.g.:

```
?- split2([X,1,-3,Y],L).
L = [[X, 1], [-3], [Y]],
X in 0..sup,
Y in 0..sup ;
;
L = [[X, 1], [-3, Y]],
X in 0..sup,
Y in inf.. -1 ;
;
L = [[X], [1], [-3], [Y]],
X in inf.. -1,
Y in 0..sup ;
;
L = [[X], [1], [-3, Y]],
X in inf.. -1,
Y in inf.. -1 ;
```

Comment: The clpfd variant mixes if-then-else with constraints which may be problematic,.. OTOH, +1 for the clever `sign(sign(...)...)`.

Comment: @repeat: so your suggestion would be to use `if_/3`, right ? Why is it even problematic ?

Comment: I was referring to the general case. clpfd goals may result in deferred goals that eventually fail. In situations like that using `(->)/2` can render the search for solutions incomplete.